# Функция при которой элемент убегает от курсора,как можно ее написать более удобно

Tags: javascript, функции, if, проверка, курсор

Итак вопрос в следующем,есть фрагмент кода который через проверку If позволяет элементу в моем случае это картинка,убегать от курсора,но выполнил лично я это не в очень удобной форме,хотел бы узнать как на ЧИСТОМ JS - это важно,без JQery выполнить данную функцию,но чтобы элемент убегал во все стороны (рандомно)а не четко туда куда я прописал,ибо у меня он бегает просто по квадрату

```
//html элемент который и убегает от курсора 
<div id="slavik" class="container">
    <img src="Без имени-1.png" width="100px">
 </div>

 //функция - при наведении курсора на элемент он убегает вправо либо вниз 
    run.onmouseover = function t() {

        if (bot == 1) slavik.style.left = "500px";
        if (bot == 2) slavik.style.top = "200px";
        if (bot == 3) slavik.style.left = "300px";
        if (bot == 4) slavik.style.top = "100px";
        if (bot == 5) slavik.style.left = "200px";
        if (bot == 6) slavik.style.top = "600px";


        bot = bot + 1;
        console.log(bot);
        if (bot == 6) bot = 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если просто рандомные left и top задавать при наведении?

```js
var elemLeft, elemTop, maxElemLeft, maxElemTop, elem;

elem = document.getElementById('slavik');

maxElemLeft = document.documentElement.clientWidth - elem.offsetWidth;
maxElemTop = document.documentElement.clientHeight - elem.offsetHeight;

elem.onmousemove = handler;

function handler() {
  elemLeft = Math.random() * maxElemLeft;
  elem.style.left = elemLeft + 'px';
  elemTop = Math.random() * maxElemTop;
  elem.style.top = elemTop + 'px';
  //console.log(elemLeft+' - '+elemTop);
}
```

```css
#slavik{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="slavik"></div>
```